# What's the difference between $V\times W$ and $V\otimes W$ where $V$ and $W$ are vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V,W$ vector spaces. I don't really understand what is $V\otimes W$. To me it looks the same that $V\times W$. Do you have any explanation ?

Comment: Seems a $\bigcirc$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V\otimes_F W$ uses $V\times W$ as a basis, generating elements subject to some algebraic relations (bilinearity and balanced-ness).

If $\dim(V)=n$ and $\dim(W)=m$, then $\dim(V\times W)$ is just $m+n$, but $\dim(V\otimes_F W)=mn$.

If you are confusing the two you need to look harder at how $V\otimes_F W$ is constructed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed, you right. Now I have a problem, is $V=span(e_1,...,e_m)$ and $W=span(u_1,...,u_n)$, then $V\otimes W$ is generated by $\{e_i\otimes u_j\}_{i,j}$. But what would be a basis of $V\times W$ ? $\{(e_i,u_j)\}_{i,j}$ ? I don't think so since $\{(e_i,u_j)\}_{ij}$ has also $mn$ vectors.

Comment: @user330587 $\{(e_i,0)\mid i\in 1\ldots n\}\cup \{(0,u_i)\mid i\in 1\ldots m\}$

Comment: Very good ! Your answer is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: So if I understand good, if $F=span((e_1,0),...,(e_m,0))$ and $G=span((0,u_1),...,(0,u_n))$, then $V\times W=F+G$, right ?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is an isomorphic copy of $V$ inside $V\times W$ and so on with $G$ and $W$.